# How to implement delete function with recoil and react.js

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I'm implementing a to-do list app using Recoil.
The function to delete items is not working properly yet. Below is a part of my code.

```
// ToDoList.js

import React from 'react';
import { useRecoilValue, useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
import { todoListState } from './atoms';

function ToDoList() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useRecoilState(todoListState);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setTodos([])
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            {todo.text}
            <button onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.id)}>DELETE</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToDoList;
```

The item is not deleted correctly and the list is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the handleDelete function to remove the item with the specified ID from the `todoListState` atom. Here's an example implementation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRecoilValue, useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
import { todoListState } from './atoms';

function ToDoList() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useRecoilState(todoListState);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setTodos((prevTodos) => prevTodos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            {todo.text}
            <button onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.id)}>DELETE</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToDoList;
```

Comment: This is correct answer